# My VPN app https request pulls .opvn files from host folder, but edits the config to web data from my site

Tags: .htaccess, https, directory, webserver, file-permissions

I have a VPN app that pulls .ovpn files from a folder on my website /home/mywebsitename/public_html/remoteovpn When I add the .opvn files to this folder and my app pulls them from https request. You can go to the files in the browser link, you can see them and read all the config no problem even dl them. But when my app pulls the files it gets the file names and makes the .opvn files, but edits the files with my website wp theme data, not the .ovpn config data. I can't figure why it is doing this.

Comment: A client side app certainly does not "edit" a server side file. So please be more precise, what _exactly_ do you observe? And what is the connection to this "wp theme"? Where does that come from?

Comment: At the start of the app the files are downloaded by the app and placed in a folder. When they are on the server the config is good. But when app downloads the files it keeps the file names but somehow adds my website code in the file. Like the https request is getting data from my site and adding it in the file and removing the config info that was in the file.

Comment: And how do you expect us to tell you what your "app" does? If it alters the files it downloads, then you need to ask the person responsible for that "app" I'd say.

Comment: it is a simple HTTP get request from app, the app works on other host i tested. It is some setting on my server sending my wp site data.

Comment: If that is what you suspect then you need to start digging deeper: I suggest two steps: 1. you need to compare the requests a browser does (correct result) with the request that "app" does (you say the result has been manipulated). What is the difference? Use a utility like `curl` to mimic the app's request so close that you get the same, corrupted result. 2. use a network sniffer, for example `wireshark` to observe the actual traffic between the "app" and the server. Is the response already altered there or not?

Comment: Beside that you need to rule out human error: you as an interpreting agent. How do you compare the results, what makes you sure it is not you observing the results that is altering the content? Also you obviously need to monitor our http server's log files closely. And check potential caching stages (proxies, network layer (android?), builtin).